# How can I reload JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on an app where initially you are a guest user, and you have an option to login. When you login, I want the `JFrame` 'reloaded'. Basically what I'm doing is `frm.dispose()` and then open the form again.

Is there a finer way to do this?

Comment: Usually, the login panel is a JDialog, and you just show more Swing components on the JFrame after the user logs into the application.

Comment: If you want help with your code, don't you think that you should post it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to `revalidate();` the frame. If that doesn't work you also have to call `repaint();`

or You can try one of the below options:

```
frame.invalidate();

frame.validate();
```